# How to use variable inside For /L Loop IN List ( Batch File Programming)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I want to place a variable value in for loop IN list. the myvariable is obtained from the user input.

Example:

```
for /L %%G IN (1 1 %myvariable%) DO command
```

If i use this syntax, the loop is never executed. Is it possible to assign IN list to for loop at runtime ?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is right, but your syntax is wrong.  It should be:

```
for /l %%G in (1, 1, %myvariable%) do command
```

Comment: Thanks.. 
I tried this syntax with commas but did not work. Please help me out.

Comment: @user1634371 - Commas are not required, but space between IN and ( is required.

Answer (score 2):

Mark has identified a missing space between IN and (, but can't tell if that is your actual code or just a typo when you created the question.

Another possibility is that your variable is being set within the same code that later expands the value. The following code will fail:

```
(
  set /p "myvariable=Enter a value: "
  echo myvariable=%myvariable%
)
```

The reason the above fails is that the % expansion occurs when the statement is parsed, and the entire block within the parentheses is treated as a single statement. So it expands to the value that existed prior to executing the SET /P.

If you want the value that exists at run time, then you need to use delayed expansion

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  set /p "myvariable=Enter a value: "
  echo myvariable=!myvariable!
)
```

This type of problem frequently occurs with IF and FOR commands. I can't tell if this is your problem because you haven't provided enough context.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what the value of `%myvariable%` is in your command that doesn't work.  Since CMD expands that out first, if its value would break the syntax of the `for` command, that could cause all sorts of problems.